# Insert string into another string at certain position in dart

Tags: string, dart, insert

How to insert a String like `"-"` into another String e.g. `"test"` at index `2` to get the following result: `"te-st"`?

In other languages like C# there exist methods like [`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but not for dart.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to insert a string at a certain index/position is using the [String.replaceRange()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceRange.html) method with a range length of zero.

```dart
final newString = "My String".replaceRange(index, index, "insertion string");
```

For convenience one could use the following extension:

```dart
extension InsertString on String {
  String insert(int index, String string) => replaceRange(index, index, string);
}

// Usage:
"test".insert(2, " "); // returns "te st"
```